# How to locate element in a page using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I am working on a project where customer sends inner html in an excel file and i need to check if that element is visible in a page. I copy past the html into Chrome developer console and check if this element is present.

How do i automate this process ? Is there any way to automate the visibility of element by html in developer console?

Comment: What kind of inner html is he sending we can check if any element with text //*[text()='anything'] is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xPath :

`//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]`

to find the text that you are looking for. However, you have mentioned about using it in the chrome console, how do you intend to automate this?